# Recommendations for learning to write games for Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe

I'm interested in writing games (simple ones thankfully) that take advantage of the Adobe AIR platform. I've looked around but I haven't found any complete tutorials that are targeted at Adobe AIR. There are some awesome Flash and Flex SDK examples, but this are all aimed at use in the browser rather than in AIR.

I'm keen for any books, tutorials and examples.

Any and all advice very welcome!

Comment: i also highly recommend Keith Peters' 2 books for any AS3 game developers - both very relevant in AIR:  1.  Making Things Move (2007):  http://goo.gl/XCrcd, 2:  Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Animation (2009):  http://goo.gl/uhFWg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just this week Lee Brimelow posted to The Flash Blog entries about the [Flixel](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=2562) framework as well as a book called [ActionScript 3.0 Game Programming University](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=2566) by Gary Rosenzweig.

neither are AIR specific, but of course they will work with AIR.